# what is regular expression to get the data after _

Tags: regex, shell

I am having a filename like:2015_q1_cricket_international.txt
How can I get the data after underscore(_).
my final output should be 2015internationalcricket

Answer (score 1):

#### Using awk

Let's create a shell variable with your file name:

```
$ fname=2015_q1_cricket_international.txt
```

Now, let's extract the parts that you want:

```
$ echo "$fname" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1 $4 $3}'
2015internationalcricket
```

How it works:

- `-F'[_.]'` tells awk to split the input anywhere it sees either a `_` or a `.`
- `print $1 $4 $3` tells awk to print the parts that you asked for

#### Using shell

```
$ echo "$fname" | { IFS='_.' read a b c d e; echo "$a$d$c"; }
2015internationalcricket
```

#### Using sed

```
$ echo "$fname" | sed -E 's/^([^_.]*)_([^_.]*)_([^_.]*)_([^_.]*).*/\1\4\3/'
2015internationalcricket
```

#### Capturing to a shell variable

If we want put the new string in a shell variable, we use *command subsitution*:

```
var=$(echo "$fname" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1 $4 $3}')

var=$(echo "$fname" | { IFS='_.' read a b c d e; echo "$a$d$c"; })

var=$(echo "$fname" | sed -E 's/^([^_.]*)_([^_.]*)_([^_.]*)_([^_.]*).*/\1\4\3/')
```

If the shell is bash, we can do this more directly:

```
IFS='_.' read a b c d e <<<"$fname"
var="$a$d$c"
```

Comment: Is there any way to take the result to a variable.So that I can make use any where in script.

Comment: @kunaal Yes.  See the updated answer for methods of creating shell variables containing the new string.

Answer (score 0):

`.*_([^_]*)_.*` gets «cricket» as `\1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Split('_') and get array of results, or you can use regular expression _[A-Za-z0-9]* which returns all the chars after the underscore which matches three sets.

All the results are returned in an Array.